# How to use Android restricted API methods ¿reflection?

Tags: android, reflection, android-package-managers

I'm developing an app that has system privileges and I want to use the intallPackage() and deletePackage() methods, which aren't visible in the regular API. I have no idea about how to use reflection to make these methods available. Does someone knows how can I access this methods from code? What are the steps to make them available on Android SDK? Any tutorials about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suggested, it can be done with reflection. To avoid any changes in the SDK causing problems it's a good idea to validate the methods first before calling them, to ensure they exists and have the correct method signature.

If you grab the Android source code you should be able to find all of the hidden methods, they are marked with a `@hide` annotation.

**Edit:**

Here is an (incomplete) example, enabling the access point programatically which should give you some clues:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
Method method = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
method.invoke(wifiManager, config, true);
```

Essentially, get a `Method` and invoke it.

Comment: Hi Philio, what I would like are the steps to make these methods available. I have never used reflection before. Do you have any idea? A tutorial link would be great.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Philio could you just add how do I validate the methods so I can mark it as correct and also mark de answer as useful. PLZ!!!

Comment: One question before awarding it as correct. I will not need to change or link to anything in the IDE?

Comment: I think `getMethod` throws an exception if the method doesn't exist.

Comment: I rarely use Java reflection, something like this might be useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html